# Flutter Sound CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "tau_sound_core":

Tags: flutter, dart

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "tau_sound_core":
In Podfile:
flutter_sound (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_sound/ios`) was resolved to 8.0.2+1, which depends on
tau_sound_core (= 8.0.2+1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `tau_sound_core (= 8.0.2+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple fix with:

```
cd ./ios
pod repo update
delete Podfile.lock
delete pods
delete .symlink
pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

First, use the `10.0` or higher, inside `Podfile` for `flutter_sound`

`platform :ios, 10.0`

Then run this to clean caches inside your project directory:

```
cd ios
pod cache clean --all
rm Podfile.lock
rm -rf .symlinks/
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod update
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
pod update
pod install
cd ..
```